# Azure Resources (Meters) RateCard Regions / is there any global Azure region ID?

Tags: json, azure

I am reading Azure RateCard prices from JSON stream (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/reference/mt219005(v=azure.100)). JSON contains info about region this way: "MeterRegion": **"US West Central"**. 
My problem is related to these values in MeterRegion. It looks like some "display name", not region "id". How to pair this MeterRegions to other systems.

E.g.: When using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Core.dll (https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net) they provide list of regions containing Name=**"westcentralus"**, DisplayName=**"US West Central"**.

As you can see, 3 different values.

**Is there anything like global Azure region ID?**

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there are only two call for the region, "Name(Location)" and "DisplayName". You can get all of the regions by the command "Get-AzureRMLocation" in powershell or by the command "az account list-locations -o table" in Azure cloud shell. You can use this region list as a reference.